# How to submit form on an external website and get generated HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, form-submit

I would like make a script using PHP (probably need JS) to send POST data to another webpage and get the result back.

For example, Domain A will have a form with a textbox and submit button, and Domain B will have a script which will fill the textbox and press the submit button and return the generated HTML page.

Comment: Using JS: you might be able to post a form to another website, you CANNOT get generated HTML. You need a server side form submission proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrape a website (javascript website) using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654541/scrape-a-website-javascript-website-using-php)

Comment: Ok. Is there possibility how can I just post a form?

Comment: @sczdavos are you using any javascript library like jquery or prototype?

Comment: @ryacii thank for your respond I've already used ppsreejith's solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following lines of code can be written on another php script,

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'the website from which you need data through post';
$fields = array(
            //post parameters to be sent to the other website
            'text'=>urlencode($_POST['text']), //the post request you send to this  script from your domain.
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Now $result will contain the text received from the other website.

Comment: When I enter that I get an error:


Notice: Undefined index: hello in C:\xampp\htdocs\proxy\test.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined variable: fields_string in C:\xampp\htdocs\proxy\test.php on line 10

Help?

Answer (score 1):

With JS: for security reasons not. Read on [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

With PHP you can do what you want, including `POST`ing other servers. For example use [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Answer (score -1):

--- Original 2012 Answer ---

Use jquery; just load the page with a $.ajax() call. If you need to, you can use "jsonp" which works around the restrictions between calling pages from different domains.

The nice thing about using javascript is that you don't need any serverside languages.

--- 2018 edit ---

I realise now that you can't do a POST with jsonp (as it is essentially read-only) so this will only work if the website accepts the form as a GET (ie, the parameters in the URL). Otherwise, best to use Curl or similar as suggested in other answers.