# Use an external webpage's form from my own website to get data (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, external

I wonder if I can use an external form of a webpage in the web from my own website. I am creating an application using the WAMP tool and I need some PHP/JavaScript/whatever script to do it.

Basically I'd have the same exactly form in my website (or at least a similar one) as the one in the external webpage - the goal of this form is only to perform a search. The user would be capable of doing the search and seeing the results posted in my website aswell and all this happening in a hidden way.

I really have no idea how to do this as I searched stackoverflow and the web looking for a solution but it really seems a little bit complicated.

Here's an image to ilustrate more or less what I want:

[image]

edit: I don't want any script or code! I Just want to know what is the best way to do this. I will eventually come to a solution (I hope!). Thanks!

Comment: basicly you want [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), right? Just check out what the external form is sending to where and grab the result. But be aware of the fact, that most (well programmed) websites won't let you do that - unless they provide an API.

Comment: @Jeff Thank you. I didn't know php curl. Extremely helpful tool, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept is called Web Scraping, you can find more about it in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

As an answer, you can write simple web scraper using PHP CURL.
CURL can submit a remote form for you and get the results of form submit, that results may need to be handled by your script to be displayed in the form you need.

This stackoverflow question and answer may clear it more for you.

[How to submit form on an external website and get generated HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030307/how-to-submit-form-on-an-external-website-and-get-generated-html)

Comment: Great answer!! I'm gonna try some code with PHP CURL and see what happens. Thank you!